# Did medieval libraries loan books to other libraries?

Tags: middle-ages, primary-source

I'd like to know this:

- Did medieval libraries loan books to other libraries -- as opposed to something like having them transcribed and sending the copy?
- What do we know about the process? (e.g., letters between Abbots, an exchange of things of equal value or a simple loan or gift)
- Are there any special terms related to this? (I'm not really up on the medieval period or religion so, pretty much any term is going to be new)
- Are there any sort of actual records about this?

Comment: I could have sworn that we'd had this question before but I can't find an earlier version. You might want to narrow things down to a particular time period (the middle ages spans a thousand years) and location (the world is a big place). My belief is that handwritten books of the time were delicate and valuable and, therefore, if you wanted to read one, you came to the library to read it.

Comment: I do not know how representative it was (he seems to have been a bit acquisitive) but Richard de Bury's [Philobiblon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Philobiblon) (1344) has recommendations for how his library should be run in ch.19; he allowed lending to scholars on security, but "for copying or transcribing we direct that no book shall be allowed outside the walls of the house"